# return result back to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, helper

i am trying to keep all my logic out of views, and have come up with the following piece of code, the though im having is that it isnt returning the actual score value, it just returns if it was a Win, lost or tie

```
def find_result(schedule)
return "not required" if schedule.event != '1' or schedule.time >= Time.now
if schedule.for.nil? or schedule.against.nil?
  "Not Entered"
else
  tie = '<b>T</b> '
  tie << schedule.for.to_i
  tie << ' - '
  tie << schedule.against.to_i
  win = '<b>W</b> '
  win << schedule.for.to_i
  win << ' - '
  win << schedule.against.to_i
  return raw tie  if schedule.for.to_i == schedule.against.to_i
  schedule.for.to_i > schedule.against.to_i ? (raw win) : "Lost"
end
```

end

Comment: A bit more of an explanation of exactly what output you expect and are getting would be helpful.

Comment: im looking for the output to be W 4 - 3, at present it is just coming through as W -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `<<` with an integer.  See the docs:
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3C

It's probably turning your win/loss numbers into characters that aren't showing up in the HTML.

Use a formatter or something, or perhaps just `to_s` rather than `to_i` when appending the numbers.

Example using string format (untested):

```
def find_result(schedule)
  return "not required" if schedule.event != '1' or schedule.time >= Time.now
  if schedule.for.nil? or schedule.against.nil?
    "Not Entered"
  elsif schedule.for.to_i < schedule.against.to_i
    "Lost"
  else
    raw "<b>%s</b> %d - %d" % [
      schedule.for.to_i == schedule.against.to_i ? 'T' : 'W',
      schedule.against.to_i,
      schedule.for.to_i
    ]
  end
```

### Edit: Refactor

Keeping logic out of the views is good, but it would be even more appropriate to
move some of this to the model, namely the result of the schedule (not entered, 
win, loss, tie)

In the example I'll make a simple inner class which encapsulates that logic, which
the Schedule makes use of to know its own result.  You could do this any number of ways
though (e.g. a module versus a class, or methods directly on Schedule)

I'll then demonstrate how you might use the new schedule in your helper using the logic provided, or simply querying for the result itself and using it as a key for a translation lookup (I18n).

Note this is untested and a little bit pseudo-codey (I'm not using any I18n library in particular, just guessing at methods and translation formatting).  But it should work with some tweaking, or at least give you an idea of another way of doing things.

```
class Schedule

  # The schedule jus instantiates a result object when you ask for one.
  # For convenience the result's to_s is it's value, e.g. "win"
  def result
    Result.new(self.for, self.against)
  end

  # delegate methods querying the result
  delegate :win?, :loss?, :tie?, :not_entered?, :to => :result

  class Result
    Values = %(win loss tie not_entered)
    Win = Values[0]
    Loss = Values[1]
    Tie = Values[2]
    NotEntered = Values[3]

    attr_reader :for, :against

    def initialize(_for, against)
      @for = _for
      @against = against
    end

    def value
      return NotEntered unless [@for, @against].all?
      case v = @for - @against
      when v.zero? then Tie
      when v > 0 then Win
      else Loss
      end
    end

    alias :to_s :value

    def not_entered?; self.value == NotEntered end
    def win?; self.value == Win end
    def loss?; self.value == Loss end
    def tie?; self.value == Tie end
  end
end

# then in your helper, something like
def find_result(schedule)
  # you'd want to refactor this requirement part too
  return "not required" if schedule.event != '1' or schedule.time >= Time.now

  # Now you could do it essentially the way you had, with ifs or a 
  # case statement or what have you, but the logic for the result is kept 
  # where it belongs, on the class.
  if schedule.not_entered?
    "Not Entered"
  elsif schedule.loss?
    "Loss"
  else
    prefix = schedule.win? ? "W" : "T"
    raw "<b>%s</b> %d - %d" % [prefix, schedule.for, schedule.against]
  end

  # OR you could use some kind of translation library using the `value` 
  # returned by the result.  Something like:
  key = ["schedule", schedule.outcome.value].join(".")
  raw I18n.translate(key, {:for => schedule.for, :against => schedule.against})
end

# if you used the latter, it would lookup the translation in some other place, 
# e.g. some config JSON, which might look like this (more or less, and 
# depending on the lib you use):

{
  "schedule": {
    "win": "<b>W</b> {{for}} - {{against}}",
    "tie": "<b>T</b> {{for}} - {{against}}",
    "loss": "Loss",
    "not_entered": "Not Entered"
  }
}

# The translation has a few advantages.  It would allow you to sub in other 
# languages, but also, it conveniently keeps all of the app's text in one 
# place, if you stick to using it.
```

Comment: perfect, is there any better logic than what im currently doing for that?